# Join table using two identifiers not just one

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have been trying to find a way to join two tables on two column identifiers.
ie in "pseudo-query":

```
 join table1 to table2 where table1.x = table2.y and table1.a = table2.b
```

Can I do this using a join statement without using a where statement explicitly? Or would it just be best to do select from table1,table2 where x=y and a=b? Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: What type of SQL? MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc? Please re-tag your question.

Comment: It is CacheSQL, a proprietary language similar in syntax to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a from clause like this:

```
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.x = table2.y and table1.a = table2.b
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
select
 *
from
    table1 a join table2 b on 
       (a.some_column = b.some_column and a.other_column = b.other_column)
```